Difference between “demonstrative pronouns” and “demonstrative determiners”
What is the difference between “demonstrative pronouns” and “demonstrative determiners”?
Are they the same thing? If not, what are the differences between them?
I definitely have searched the dictionary for differences between “pronouns” and “determiners” (from the Cambridge Dictionary), but I’m not sure if I understand the differences between “demonstrative pronouns” and “demonstrative determiners”?
I found that both demonstrative category contains word like “this”, “that”, “these”, “those”. So, I’m not sure the exactly difference between them.
I hope anyone explain to me, please.

The difference is in the nouns themselves; take a close look at the word formation and at the meanings in a dictionary (pro + noun, determine + er)

Sigh. Sorry, but your question has been close-voted by serial close-voters who hate grammar questions. Also ones who cannot tell the difference between a part of speech and a grammatical relation and a phrasal category. I'll see if I can get it reopened for you. CamGEL, for example, state that all English demonstratives are determinatives, and none are pronouns. This is a good question for EL&U.

This question is similar to: Need explanation about demonstrative determiner ... Also, what's the difference between demonstrative determiners and demonstrative pronouns? If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

I suggest leaving both questions open, as this one focuses on the difference between the pronouns and determines, and that one on a specific example.

From thesaurus.com

A demonstrative pronoun is a pronoun used to point to specific people or things.
e.g. That looks like a poisonous snake.

From langeek.co

Demonstrative determiner is a type of determiner that is used to point to a specific noun or noun phrase and specify its number and distance. They help to identify the noun that is being referred to in a sentence.
e,g. That snake looks poisonous
or That man over there is my teacher

In the first case "That" replaces the noun,.  In the second case "That" qualifies a noun

The Cambridge Grammar of the English Language (Huddleston and Pullum 2002) states that even in your first example, the word that is a demonstrative determiner (using your terminology). In fact they would say that in English, there are no demonstrative pronouns.

I still confused should I accept this answer or not, I think this answer still doesn’t answer my question.

@user1176409 A confusion has been introduced - CGEL(Huddleston and Pullum) has one view - other grammars take the more traditional view. These latter see (i) the "that" in "That fits/irritates/burns, etc you" as a pronoun - which must have a referent to be understood.

@Greybeard I agree on this one.

@ishtar You can read about it here in ASIEG, will only take 10-15 mins or so, max.

@ishtar The basic idea is that in such NPs the determinative retains its syntactic function as Determiner whilst taking on the syntactic function of the ellipted or implied nominal (i.e. 'Head' of the NP). Such constructions are considered fused Head NPs, and the actual syntactic function of the determinative (or the determinative phrase, if there is more than one word) is labelled 'Determiner-Head'.

@Greybeard What you talkin about Willis? Nobody argues that 'that' does not need a referent to be understood, or that it's not deictic. And it makes no sense to start pontificating about confusion being introduced if you do not recognise the wild confusion and reduplication in the analysis you prefer. It's the traditionalists who require extra words all over the place - and can't tell the difference between a syntactic function and a part of speech. 2 that 's, 2 these 'es, 2 some 's, 2 all 's, 2 each 'es, 2 few 's, ... (cont)

@Greybeard 2 any 's, 2 another 's, 3 little 's, 2 much 'es und so weiter, und so weiter. Huddleston and Pullum et al only have one of each of those. They can simply take part in more than one type of construction - just like the members of every other word class.

According to common definitions, like this one from Merriam-Webster, pronouns are "any of a small set of words (such as I, she, he, you, it, we, or they) in a language that are used as substitutes for nouns or noun phrases and whose referents are named or understood in the context".
'Demostrative pronouns' is a bit of a misnomer as they do not actually substitute for nouns or noun phrases.
The idea that there is a pronoun that is based on examples like the following where at first glance it seems to have the same function as an actual pronoun it.

[The dog with the long tail] is not my dog.
[That] is not my dog.
[It] is not my dog.

But a more univerally applicable analysis classes that as simply a determinative, recognizing that that in the below examples is not substituting for a noun or a noun phrase - the noun has simply been removed, leaving the rest of the structure intact. Compare with pronoun it.

[That dog over there] is my dog.
[That over there] is my dog.   [acceptable]
*[It over there] is my dog.  [unacceptable]
[It] is my dog. [acceptable]

Since we can always add the head noun back in with that when used without a head noun, something impossible with pronouns, it's preferable to just say that they are all determiner uses of that.

The over there test doesn't work. You can say Look at them over there where them over there is an NP. But this doesn't necessarily mean that them here is not a pronoun.

' ... a more universally applicable analysis' means 'if one prefers to lump in a chosen way rather than split'.

@JK2 Funny how that only works in certain, almost idiomatic situations. She over there is my friend?

Even so, your claim "that in the below examples is not substituting for a noun or a noun phrase - the noun has simply been removed, leaving the rest of the structure intact" is incorrect. That sure can substitute for the NP That dog over there in That is my dog.

I'll not join the naysayers yet. But I do think that they do  'substitute' for NPs, not least because  they are one-word NPs! However, you are right, of course, in the sense that they are determinatives functioning as Fused Determiner-Head within fused NPs.

The "demonstrative" part indicates the meaning of such words as this and that, whereas the "pronoun/determiner" part indicates the syntax of such words.
In traditional grammar, including A Comprehensive Grammar of the English Language by Quirk, et al., the same demonstratives are classified into different lexical categories (i.e., parts of speech) depending on their syntax. Therefore, if the demonstrative combines with a noun to form a noun phrase (e.g., this man is...) thereby determining the noun, it's called a demonstrative determiner. If the demonstrative alone forms a noun phrase (e.g., this is...), it's called a demonstrative pronoun.
So the distinction is rather straightforward.
